# is there some documentation on all methods of PixBuf, especially replace_data? (gtk3)

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gdkpixbuf, pixbuf

I was wondering where I can find the documentation from all of the methods that are implemented in `PixBuf` (found via `dir`, python3):

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__gdoc__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gpointer__', '__grefcount__', '__gsignals__', '__gt__', '__gtype__', '__hash__', '__info__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_force_floating', '_ref', '_ref_sink', '_unref', '_unsupported_data_method', '_unsupported_method', 'add_alpha', 'apply_embedded_orientation', 'bind_property', 'bind_property_full', 'chain', 'compat_control', 'composite', 'composite_color', 'composite_color_simple', 'connect', 'connect_after', 'connect_data', 'connect_object', 'connect_object_after', 'copy', 'copy_area', 'deserialize', 'disconnect', 'disconnect_by_func', 'emit', 'emit_stop_by_name', 'equal', 'fill', 'find_property', 'flip', 'force_floating', 'freeze_notify', 'from_pixdata', 'g_type_instance', 'get_bits_per_sample', 'get_byte_length', 'get_colorspace', 'get_data', 'get_file_info', 'get_file_info_async', 'get_file_info_finish', 'get_formats', 'get_has_alpha', 'get_height', 'get_n_channels', 'get_option', 'get_options', 'get_pixels', 'get_properties', 'get_property', 'get_qdata', 'get_rowstride', 'get_width', 'handler_block', 'handler_block_by_func', 'handler_disconnect', 'handler_is_connected', 'handler_unblock', 'handler_unblock_by_func', 'hash', 'install_properties', 'install_property', 'interface_find_property', 'interface_install_property', 'interface_list_properties', 'is_floating', 'list_properties', 'load', 'load_async', 'load_finish', 'new', 'new_for_string', 'new_from_bytes', 'new_from_data', 'new_from_file', 'new_from_file_at_scale', 'new_from_file_at_size', 'new_from_inline', 'new_from_resource', 'new_from_resource_at_scale', 'new_from_stream', 'new_from_stream_async', 'new_from_stream_at_scale', 'new_from_stream_at_scale_async', 'new_from_stream_finish', 'new_from_xpm_data', 'new_subpixbuf', 'notify', 'notify_by_pspec', 'override_property', 'props', 'qdata', 'read_pixel_bytes', 'read_pixels', 'ref', 'ref_count', 'ref_sink', 'replace_data', 'replace_qdata', 'rotate_simple', 'run_dispose', 'saturate_and_pixelate', 'save_to_bufferv', 'save_to_callbackv', 'save_to_stream_finish', 'savev', 'scale', 'scale_simple', 'serialize', 'set_data', 'set_properties', 'set_property', 'steal_data', 'steal_qdata', 'stop_emission', 'stop_emission_by_name', 'thaw_notify', 'to_string', 'unref', 'watch_closure', 'weak_ref']
```

I am particularly interested in `replace_data`, as I need to update the reference to the data in the PixBuf (would that be possible?).

Any idea on where I can find that documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main GdkPixbuf documentation is https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/

Python-specific documentation is https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GdkPixbuf-2.0